# Tomcats warning message on startup

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I've got this message when starting a tomcat server :

```
org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was
 not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Even though I've installed the apr along with some other stuff like this :

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev build-essential libapr1 libapr1-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev -y
```

This is where I found the info that I need to install it:
http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/

Comment: Did you configure the library paths via `setenv.sh` as described in the section "Install and tests -> UNIX"?

Comment: @fateddy setenv.sh: No such file or directory which is odd, I'm using tomcat 8

Comment: If it does not exist just create it.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install `libtcnative`, which is the JNI library that Tomcat actually calls.

Comment: how do I do that? I can't install it with sudo apt-get install

Comment: My bad, it's actually `libtcnative-1`.